# Why can't I find or locate a '.txt' filetype created by python on the current working directory?

Tags: python, file-io

Well, I am having some issues with the file I/O in Python. I exactly don't know why, but my current working directory isn't showing up the file which I created with python. For example, the code looks something like this -

```
import os
print(os.getcwd())
print(os.listdir('.'))
f = open('text.txt','w+')
f.write('HelloWorld')
f.close()
```

The problem is, the file which has been created by python is not showing up. I will add two images to make my confusion clearer. The first image contains the output of above given example. It clearly shows that the file was created.
[First_one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Izp93.png)

On the second image, you will see that though the file was created it does not show up in the current working directory. I have no clue why!
[Second_image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/diNth.png)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found the solution. A technical problem arose because of the "Antivirus" sandbox. Just disabled it and runs all good.